# JNI passing a null argument to Java method

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

**EDIT**

I've finally found out that the problem was caused by the null value not being null after all, because one of the constructors didn't initialize the value to zero. With this knowledge, I'd like to reword my question to following:

*Is it safe to pass NULL/0/nullptr to Java method through JNI if the argument is supposed to be null?*

The sources I found so far gave mixed results – some of them say that NULL in C and null in Java are the same thing when using JNI. Some, like the one linked in the remudada's answer, suggests that it may not be entirely correct.

**OLD QUESTION**

Is it possible to call Java method with a null argument when using JNI?

I've tried passing null (either 0, NULL or nullptr), but that causes Segmentation fault. I have also tried `NewGlobalRef` with null argument, but that just returns null.

Assume following Java code:

```java
class Main {
  public void javaFoo(Object o) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Calling this method from C++ will look similar to this:

```cpp
env->CallVoidMethod(object, javaFooID, value);
```

Now what do I have to do if I want `value` to be null?

The problem is that I can't easily avoid passing null objects. There are various setters which have multiple parameters which may or may not be null and where null serves as an invalid value:

```java
public void setFoo(Object a, Object b, Object c, Object d) {
  ... // any parameter can be null
}
```

Comment: It shouldn’t create a segfault. What’s your method doing with the object?

Comment: It just sets value of a member variable. For now the value is left unused. However, I think the problem may be lying somewhere else. My latest wild guess is that the `value` may be left unitialized instead of being null in some cases, which would trigger the crash.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it's OK to return NULL. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/Za6No6Pjfj4

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was accepted, as it mention that it can "return NULL" while the question ask about passing an argument to a Java function call.